# Installing Scrapy with pip, but come across an error of Cryptography, indicating compiling fails

Tags: python, cryptography, scrapy, pip, suse

My OS is Suse 11 Enterprise SP3.

I try to install `scrapy` by `pip`.

But when compiling `Cryptography`, it indicates somthing wrong with the compiling of `_openssl.c`

I have never edited anything of `_openssl.c`.
Dont know why this happened.

Very eager to know how to solve it .

Part of the log :

```
    building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  *gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/python2.7/include/python2.7 -c*** build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o*
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:680: error: function definition declared ‘typedef’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:680: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: In function ‘LHASH_OF’:
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:680: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘Cryptography_LHASH_OF_CONF_VALUE’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:682: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_ACCESS_DESCRIPTION’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:683: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_DIST_POINT’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:684: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_POLICYQUALINFO’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:685: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_POLICYINFO’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:686: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_ASN1_INTEGER’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:687: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_GENERAL_SUBTREE’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:699: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_ASN1_OBJECT’
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:700: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘Cryptography_STACK_OF_X509_OBJECT’
  In file included from build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:711:
```

Comment: it may needs to install `openssl` or `openssl-dev` using `apt-get` or similar.

Comment: some modules are written not only in Python but also in C and sometimes pip has to compile this C elements - and it needs some extra elements in system - like C header files or C libraries.

Comment: you didn't show full error message - maybe there are other usefull information below last line.

Comment: There's a warning in the Scrapy docs about conflicts etc. It is recommended to never install Scrapy globally but only inside its own virtual environment (you can use the Python package `virtualenv` for that). This might be related, not entirely sure though. Did you use a virtual environment or did you try to install globally?

Comment: I have no experience with SUSE but you'll probably need to install `gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel` using your package manager. That's what's indicated in [cryptography install page](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux).

Comment: @Celebrian I have used virtualenv and did all these above in a virtual python environment . Thus it might not be the reason. Thanks a lot for your comment anyway.

Comment: @paultrmbrth  I remembered I had installed the packages you mentioned above.  It's a very good idea to read the cryptography related pages. I will read it carefully. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @furas I tried to update the C header files of openssl ,however it didn't work . I will paste more error log when back at work .Thanks a lot.